# text of the textview sending

Tags: android

i have two activities each contain its own textview any one help me that when i click the one textview text the text goes to the another textview of the second activity please any on help me in this problem

Answer (score 0):

In activity A.
TextView aTv = findViewById(R.id.aTextView);
String aText = aTv.getText().toString();
Intent i = new Intent(bClass.class); // your other activity
i.putExtra("myText", aText);
startActivity(i);

In the onCreate of Activity B:
String aText = this.getIntent().getStringExtra("myText");

TextView bTv = findViewById(R.id.bTextView);
bTv.setText(aText);

Is that what you were looking to do? I'm into a few beers so there may be a few typo's but that's the idea. :)